# How to insert a DOM value in a react React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a HTML page, and I am inserting inside as a component a Reactjs.
I am reading the DOM with JavaScript vanilla and I want to insert it on this new react script.

```
<HTML>
<div id="element">the value I want</div>
<div id="root"></div>
</HTML>
```

The div id "root" is where the react was inserted
I want to play with the "value" from the DOM, but inside of React

Can I do it? How

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass it as a prop, your component won't rely on the structure of the DOM, making it a little bit more reusable and testable:

```
const value = document.getElementById('element').value;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App value={value}>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

or as Juan Mendes mentioned, pass in the elementId as a prop.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can add it to `componentWillMount` before the initial render.

HTML

```
<div id="element">the value I want</div>
<div id="root"></div>
```

JSX

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const { element } = this.props;
    this.text = document.getElementById(element).textContent;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.text}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test element="element" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a57sh950/2/)**

Comment: To make this slightly more reusable, I suggest taking the id of the element (or the element itself) instead of hardcoding it

Comment: @JuanMendes, like that?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this

```
<div ref={(ref) => { this.myDiv = ref; }}  />
```

And then you can get what ever you want from it with.

```
this.myDiv
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work if the element is within the React application? The OP is asking for something different.